# Visual Studio 2015, installed font is not applied

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, editor

I installed (as [MS recommend](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314960/how-to-install-or-remove-a-font-in-windows)) a [font](http://input.fontbureau.com/) and tried to assign it into '*Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors*' but doesn't work.

**Lucida Console** font applied:

[image: VS2015 change font issue - Lucida font]

**InputMonoCondensed** font applied:

[image: VS2015 change font issue - Input font]

Restarted Visual Studio and my computer without success, what could be wrong?

*Notes:*

- *OS: Windows 10 Pro*
- *VS: Community 2015 v14 Update 3*
- *.NET Framework: v4.6*
- *All were installed and updated into a new computer.*

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. Which font did you install, what happened when you did so, have you tried any other fonts, do those work, etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Changed the title to '...is not applied'. Font is linked. Other fonts are applied correctly (check the images).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a known issue documented on Input download website http://input.fontbureau.com/workarounds/

Here is the relevant part:

> In certain configurations of Visual Studio (2010–2013), the default Input installation will not display at all, and instead you’ll see Courier. A workaround is to customize and download a four-style family (which will appear in your font menu as “Input”), rather than selecting from the whole family. Some users reported that they had to reboot their system for the change to take effect.

Solution is mentioned, on the download page http://input.fontbureau.com/download/ chose "Customize your download" option and select "Download a custom four-style family", based on InputMonoCondensed.
Install this font after downloading, and select the font named Input (just Input, not InputMono or InputMonoCondensed for instance) into Visual Studio options:

[image: Select Input fo,t]

That's it!

Now you can edit using Input font, that's actually what I personally use.
[image: Example of Visual Studio editor using Input font]

Comment: I removed previously installed Input family fonts and followed your instructions. Works like a charm. I had to modify font settings into SublimeText and other editors but it was the less. Thank you!.